# Merge two lists into one component by component

Tags: r, list, merge

I have two lists, plus an empty list:

```
    A <- list(1:4,5:8,9:12)
    B <- c("a","b")
    C <- vector(mode = "list")
```

I would like to merge A and B into C as following:

```
    C[[1]][1] = A[[1]]         C[[1]][2] = B
    C[[2]][1] = A[[2]]         C[[2]][2] = B
    C[[3]][1] = A[[3]]         C[[3]][2] = B
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

How about `C <- lapply(A, function(x) list(x, B))`?

for example:

```r
A <- list(1:4,5:8,9:12)
B <- c("a","b")

C <- lapply(A, function(x) list(x, B))
# C <- lapply(A, list, B) # also works

all(
  C[[1]][[1]] == A[[1]],
  C[[2]][[1]] == A[[2]],
  C[[3]][[1]] == A[[3]],
  
  C[[1]][[2]] == B,
  C[[2]][[2]] == B,
  C[[3]][[2]] == B
)
```

note that you'll need double `[[` since each element of `C` is also a list (`C[[1]][[1]]` rather than `C[[1]][1]`).